# How do I view two movies from same computer on different monitors?

Tags: display

I would like to run two or more different movies from the same computer on two separate monitors. What type of software or hardware do I need?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is a programming related Q&A site.

Comment: @ciprian this site is for programmng only. There is another site, superuser.com, which is for advanced computer questions.

Comment: Can someone fix the tags?

Answer (score 7):

this is for [superuser.com](http://superuser.com)..

by the way you will need:

- a video card with two video outputs (either VGA/DVI or two DVIs)
- two monitors
- an OS that supports two monitors (short answer: any OS)

Everything more is just trivial since your OS will handle two monitors and you can easily open two movies and move one of them on the other monitor. The only problem would be to have two separate audio outputs, this will need at least a PCI audio board (in addition to the onboard one of your mobo) and different settings per video player.

Comment: downvoting for what? I voted to move to superuser.com and also answered (since being rude to be rude is just stupid).

Comment: Don't encourage OT questions by answering them. Wait for the question to be moved to the appropriate site.

Comment: I would paste my answer on superuser.com. You don't educate people by not encouraging them but explaining what's wrong with or without answers. Unless you think that peoples are like sheeps :)

Comment: @Jack that's what comments are for.

Comment: +1, I think downvoting a well-intentioned answers is not a 'Best Practice"

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what your trying to accomplish(are you using a DVD, or video file?). You could always just open one movie, then open the second in a second media player, and drag it to the second screen.

But again, what exactly are you trying to accomplish other than playing two or more movies? You will also have audio conflicts.